# Extending custom shortcode to also be called directly from theme PHP pages

Tags: theme-development, shortcode

I created the following shortcode which works well in returning the featured image of any given post I am on with a size...

```
function mfeaturedimage( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'size' => 'medium',
    ), $atts );
    return the_post_thumbnail("{$a['size']}");
}
add_shortcode( 'feature', 'mfeaturedimage' );
```

...But how can I evolve this to "also" be called directly from my content-single.php file, (i.e. **feature();**)

To sum it up, I want a single function that is flexible enough to work as a shortcode and also as a function declaration statement, but I'm not sure how to structure it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand, but you can call

```
echo do_shortcode("[feature site='your-choice']");
```

within the content-single.php file. If that isn't enough, I suppose a function like this could be made:

```
function feature($size){
    echo do_shortcode("[feature size='{$size}']");
}
```

Comment: This is cool, I didn't know do_shortcode() could reference my original shortcode function and display it on a custom php page with echo.  That is exactly what I needed. Thanks